# D unknown function _xopEquals

Tags: d

I downloaded druntime from https://github.com/xomboverlord/xomb-bare-bones/tree/master. It's druntime made for bare bones XOmB OS. If I want to compile it to object files, dmd return error "undefined identifier _xopEquals". Then I was look to official druntime and I found function _xopEquals. When I add this function to XOmB druntime, nothing changed...

I found this function in druntime/src/object_.d :

```
bool _xopEquals(in void*, in void*)
{
     throw new Error("TypeInfo.equals is not implemented");
}
```

And I add it to module where DMD invoke the error.

Comment: What's the definition of the function you used and in which file did you put it? I've never used the xomb thing but I have done my own druntime...

Comment: try putting it in your own runtime's object.d.

Comment: It solved this problem. But many other orrors raise :(. D dependenci on druntime will ruin me...anyway, really thanks for help

Comment: here's the minimal one i did btw: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/minimal.zip a lot of the language works with a fairly small runtime, stripped binaries are about 30 KB

Comment: Another problem, I compile object.d file to object file. this is OK. Thank I compile my test file to object file, OK. BUT If I want to link it together, LD return many errors undefined reference to: D9invariant12_d_invariantFC6ObjectZv. Strange.

Comment: there's another module, invariant.d, required by the runtime as well. my zip should have one, it can be a pretty short file

Comment: Thanks, I have another problem ... Now it's return "undefined reference to memcpy". But, I remove every call memcpy and everything is solved without dependeci on libc. In function _d_arraycopy was memcpy, now it isn't. I don't know why it is want memcpy...

Comment: And I have set version = bare_metal

Comment: memcpy is sometimes output as an intrinsic by the compiler... it might help to add an implementation of it to your file so it can use that without needing libc even if the reference is generated.

Comment: Perfect, it is now working, thanks. Another question xD. I write char * str = "Hellow world".dup.ptr. But, compiler can't find symbols. Where is in the original druntime definition of dup? It's array, isn't it? But I can't find it...

Comment: That symbol is _adDupT, declared in druntime/src/rt/lifetime.d. Most these symbols can be found by just grepping the source

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the first question?
2. Yes, druntime's documentation is on this page: http://dlang.org/phobos/index.html . All modules in the `core` package are druntime modules. DMD's Phobos distribution contains druntime. However, some other implementations may or may not do so. [GDC project](http://gdcproject.org), for an example, distributes a separated `libgdruntime.a` from `libgphobos2.a` .

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I need documentation for DEEP features...not for Phobos library. Yes, I known, Phobos is distributed with druntime...

Comment: I don't think this level of thing is documented at all, not even in the compiler's source comments.